# How to copy 1 TeamCity artifact to 2 target locations?

Tags: teamcity

This doesn't work - the second line "overrides" the first, so `foo.dll` only ends up in `lib/`.

```
bin/foo.dll => release!bin/
bin/foo.dll => release!lib/
```

I need to *copy* `foo.dll` to both `bin/` and `lib/` - is that possible?

Comment: As workaround for one of the cases to use something like "./bin/foo.dll" or "bin/foo*.dll"

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "for one of the cases"

Comment: i mean you have two configs. and for one of them use `*` in filename